# AsyncTask update UI multiple times

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm trying to update the UI multiple times in an AsyncTask.
First of all the UI should update, if a request was accepted and later it should run the publishProgress, but If I return a value in the requestAccepted method the other acceptedFiles method will never be executed, but I want it to execute and update the UI before from this task

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(FileInformationHandler... params) {
    try {
        handler.createSecureSocket("192.168.3.29", 7431);

        ProtocolHandler phandler = new ProtocolHandler(handler.getInputStream(), handler.getOutputStream());
        phandler.sendInitialisation();

        ConfirmationHandler cHandler = new ConfirmationHandler(handler.getInputStream(), handler.getOutputStream());
        cHandler.addListener(new ConfirmationReceivedListener() {
            @Override
            public void requestAccepted(boolean b) {
                // Update UI without stopping the asynctask
            }

            @Override
            public void acceptedFiles(int[] ints) {
                fileSender.addListener(new ProcessListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void processChanged(int i, long l) {
                        publishProgress(i);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Are there any errors in logcat?

Comment: No because, this is a question how to do it and not "there is an error". This "method the other code is never executed" was a finding :)

Comment: Are you sure there is no problem with `ProtocolHandler` and `ProtocolHandler`? Are they your written classes?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you don't need to use an Async task if you are anyways doing the long running operation in a separate thread and have callbacks for different states.

So in your case why can't you simply so all of this in the main thread and in the callbacks just update the UI.

But if you still want to use the Async task then since the `doInBackground` executes in a separate thread, you can do whatever long running operation is in the method serially and keep using the `publishProgress` method to update the UI whenever you want. since you are using the callback interface in your case the method will return `null` and the control with go into the 'onPostExecute'.

IMO using a callback interface in the `doInBackground` method is not the right approach and defeats the purpose of asyncTask async task.